# How to I fix an http error code 400? (firebase auth related)

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, http-post

I have a static website where I am trying to configure it to communicate with firebase particularly the authentication bit, but I have 2 errors displaying in the console  [Console network tab view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvZrm.png) [console: network tab waterfall view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh0jI.png)

now what is happening exactly is that I made a single html page to handle authentication

this page is called (auth.html)

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithCustomToken, signOut } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-auth.js";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp({
    apiKey: "API key",
    authDomain: "firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "fireauth",
    storageBucket: "appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "162620739",
    appId: "1:16262739:web:634d6f3357004eced9e"
  });

// Above initialization details are incorrect deliberately (they aren't the issue/ focus now)

const auth = getAuth(app);


createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });

  
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
.then((userCredential) => {
  // Signed in 
  const user = userCredential.user;
  // ...
})
.catch((error) => {
  const errorCode = error.code;
  const errorMessage = error.message;
});

signInWithCustomToken()
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in
    var user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });

// Detect auth state
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
    console.log("Logged in!");
    alert("You are logged in!");
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
    console.log("Anonymous mode (signed out)");
  }
});


signOut(auth).then(() => {
  // Sign-out successful.
  console.log("logged out")
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error happened.
  alert("Network error");
});
```

```html
<body>
  <!--- Login section --->
  <div id="login-div" class="container">
    <div class="div1">
    <form class="login-form"><h1>Login to continue</h1>
      <p>Avatar ID</p>
      <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      <p>Secret Key</p>
      <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      <button type="signInWithEmailAndPassword" disabled>Login</button><br><a onclick="thenewcallout3()" href="#">Reset my secret key</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


  <!--- register section --->
    <div id="user-div" class="div2">
    <form class="login-form">
      <h2>Register to continue</h2><br>
      <p>Enter your email address</p>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Avatar ID" id="avatarId" required>
      <p>Password</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Secret key"><br><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat your secret key" id="secretKey" required><br><br>
      <p id="up">I accept that my privacy & actions online are my responsibility not StarlinkBw</p><input type="checkbox" required>
      <button type="createUserWithEmailAndPassword" disabled>Register</button>
    </form></div>
    
    <!---Account reset--->
    <div class="fixAcc"><h1>Password reset</h1><input type="email" placeholder="Enter your Avatar ID"><br><br><button disabled>Request new key</button></div>


    <!--- Portal --->
    <nav class="menu">
      <header>Starlink <span>[X]</span></header>
      <ol>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="../welcome.html">Go back</a></li>
          <!--- views registration form & hides login --->
        <li class="menu-item"><a onclick="thenewcallout()" href="#" >Login</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a onclick="thenewcallout2()" href="#" >Register</a></li>
          <ol class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="">Social networking</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="">Self care</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="">Entertainment</a>
            </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="">Productivity</a>
          </ol>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="../star/standard/terms&conditions.html">Terms & Conditions</a>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>          
      <footer><button aria-label="Toggle Menu">Toggle</button></footer>
    </nav>


    <script src="../scripts/sl.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/jl.js"></script>
    <script type = 'text/javascript' src="../scripts/status-check.js"></script>

    <!--- Firebase --->
    <script src="../scripts/sync.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

which is linked to a JavaScript file called ./sync.js.

I managed to initialize firebase successfully (I think) and reports the current user (me in dev mode) is logged out in the console <[Console user view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn3St.png)> (which is great news) but I am having trouble sending the user data from the static auth.html page to firebase. what is the issue with my sync.js file?

to see the current perfomance of the website in real life, you can visit [My website](https://starlinkbw.github.io/portal/offline_VS_Online/auth.html) please note all auth triggering buttons are disabled in the actual website so that I can fix this error.

Comment: you cut off the error message in the first pretty picture ... post the error as text in the question

Comment: I updated it into full view

Comment: now we can't see the error **message** (the thing that's telling you what is wrong) AT ALL - brilliant step backwards - how about you post the error **message** as text, in the question, like I suggested ... that way, it can be read

Comment: oh the network waterfall view sorry, i added it next to the 1st picture

Comment: so, which line of your code is sending that request with invalid arguments? Can't see any client code that even makes a request, yet, that seems to be the issue

Comment: That's the thing after tinkering with the firebase code I was getting local errors at first, then when all seemed okay-ish (firebase began sending those errors into my console). because the script is set to run when a user lands on the page

Comment: looking at auth.html, you seem to just call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and `signInWithCustomToken` and `signOut` all at once, no idea where the value of the arguments are coming from, you just simply call those functions when that page loads

Comment: now I get it ... email and password are the inputs with those id's - that answers why the code actually runs ..., but email and password are input elements, not their value, that's why the error is complaining about objects on a scalar field ...

Comment: but you do realise you call those functions `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` etc on page load, not on any submit ... right ... and `<button type="signInWithEmailAndPassword"` is meaningless ... button type can be one of `submit`, `reset` or `button` only

Comment: So the issue is the disabled buttons in the html? should I change them to type="submit"? if so how will they know where to send the data to? if not the issue is in the JavaScript that the script doesnt know where to get the data from? isnt it that with Auth the data is either from the user or the server?

Comment: no, that's NOT the issue (though it is **an** issue for later, once you learn how javascript code works)... the issue is you are calling those functions when the page loads, before you even have a change to enter data into the fields, and you run all of them in parallel, so think about what your code is doing ... createUserWithEmailAndPassword and signInWithEmailAndPassword and signInWithCustomToken and signOut all at once

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix to the problem
thanks to the advice Bravo gave me

I removed a few declaration like signingInWithCustomToken & signout (I am going need signout later though)
signing in using custom token is a little more complicated since it uses the Admin SDK which I failed several times trying to implement it.

I added event listeners to import data from specific input elements fields (most likely which caused the 400 error due to value assignment mismatch)

which turned my auth.html & sync.js to look like the code snippets attached

although Auth works, the system faces issues like (network errors) when ad-blockers are running/ enabled

as for the console there is nothing to report there, it doesnt show any errors anymore

This is the end result after authenticating [Auth result within client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGhap.png) & [firebase updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtUkR.png)

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-auth.js";


// Your web app's Firebase configuration

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "Your API key,
  authDomain: "firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "your project",
  storageBucket: "appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "11739",
  appId: "1:162621739:web:634d6f04eced9e"
};

// Again the above configurations are incorrect delibaratetly (but not the main focus)

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);


submitData.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
.then((userCredential) => {
  // Signed in 
  const user = userCredential.user;
  // ...
  alert("Account creation success! Welcome " + email);
  window.location.replace("https://google.com");
})
.catch((error) => {
  const errorMessage = error.message;
  // ..
  alert(errorMessage);
});
});

submitLogin.addEventListener('click', (f) => {

  var avatar = document.getElementById("avatar").value;
  var secretKey = document.getElementById("secretKey").value;
  
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, avatar, secretKey)
.then((userCredential) => {
  // Signed in 
  const user = userCredential.user;
  // ...
  alert("You are logged in as: " + avatar);
  window.location.replace("https://google.com");
})
.catch((error) => {
  const errorCode = error.code;
  alert(errorCode);
});
});
```

```html
  <!--- Login section --->
  <div class="container">
    <form class="login-form"><h1>Login to continue</h1>
      <p>Avatar ID</p>


      <!--- Avatar & secretKey fields here --->
      <input type="text" id="avatar" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="email">
      <p>Secret Key</p>
      <input type="password" id="secretKey" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password">
      
      <button type="button" id="submitLogin" name="submitLogin">Login</button><br><a onclick="thenewcallout3()" href="#">Reset my secret key</a>
    </div>


  <!---Register section ---->
    <div class="div2">
      <div class="login-form">
        <h2>Register to continue</h2><br>
          <p>Enter your email address</p>


            <!----Email & password registration fields here ---->
            <input type="email" placeholder="Avatar ID" id="email" autocomplete="email">
              <p>Password</p>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Secret key"><br><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat your secret key" id="password" autocomplete="new-password"><br><br>
          <p id="up">I accept that my privacy & actions online are my responsibility not StarlinkBw</p><input type="checkbox">
      <button id="submitData" name="submitData">Register</button></div>
    </div>

  Account reset section 
  <section>
    <div class="fixAcc">
      <h1>Password reset</h1>
        <input placeholder="Enter your Avatar ID" autocomplete="email" id="email-P-Reset"><br>
          <br>
        <button>Request new key</button>
      </div>
    </section></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see..., I Had the same problem Today and I realized that the configurations in my code was okay, what I need to do is go to my firebase console on project shortcuts and click on authentication -> go to sign-in Method and on the provider, make sure the email/password provider is enabled, if it's not added click on add provider and select email/password and then enable it